# Scene builder 8.5 installing error

Tags: scenebuilder

instalando scene builder 8.5 en W10, me sale este error, la instalación por lo que entiendo; si ha tenido lugar, ya que el programa me aparece, es al ejecutarse cuando sucede esto:
`Class com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/SceneBuilderApp notfound.`

Seguido de otro que dice: `failed to launch JVM`

Comment: Parece que no tienes bien instalado el entorno Java en sí mismo. ¿Por qué no desinstalas todo y luego instalas el paquete de NetBeans completo, que trae Java, Scene Builder, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias! estoy trabajando con eclipse. así que reinstalaré todo a ver... gracias!

Answer (score 0):

He intentado resetear Java, como me dijo A.Cedano, y no me ha funcionado, no creo que Java tenga problemas ya que lo uso en muchas otras ocasiones sin fallo. Alguna otra idea...??

[image: Aquí mi versión]

Dejo por aqui tambien fotos de los errores al arrancar el SceneBuilder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]